# My second scanf is not working - what can I do?

Tags: c, scanf, clion

My second `scanf` in this code is not working, the computer doesn't wait for me to enter the second value.

I know when it happens with `%c` it is just need to put a space before the `%`
But can't make it work with `%f`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float a, p;
    printf("Insira seu peso: "); scanf("%.1f", &p);
    printf("Insira sua altura: "); scanf("%.2f", &a);
}
```

Comment: I'll refer you to [the Linux scanf man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) as it's probably as good a source as any. Reading it, you'll notice that `.` is not a valid formatting character. Your compiler should have warned you about this but apparently did not. You might try compiling your code at an online compiler such as [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) where you'll see the error messages that are produced regarding your formatting strings.

Comment: FYI, on gcc you will get a warning like this: `warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat]`. Which is telling you exactly what others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

The dot `.` is not a valid format flag character in the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) family of functions.  The formats are related to the `printf()` family of formats (and that's not accidental) but they are far from identical.

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character '`%`' … after which the following appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional assignment-suppressing character '`*`'.
> - An optional non-zero decimal integer that specifies the maximum field width.
> - [CX] ⌦ An optional assignment-allocation character '`m`'. ⌫
> - An option length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
> - A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied. The valid conversion specifiers are described below.

No mention of `.` in there.

Answer (score 3):

Actually not a single scanf is working properly in the code. When we use scanf we are just going to get the answer from the user so we do not need a (.) before the variable "f", float in there. We can make adjustments when we print the number that the user has put. Below I have shown an example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
float a, p;
printf("\n Please enter 1st value: ");
scanf("%f", &p);
printf("\n Please enter 2nd value: ");
scanf("%f", &a);

printf("\n The value of p is: %.1f", p);
printf("\n The value of a is: %.2f", a);



printf("\n\n");

system("PAUSE");
return(0);
}
```